# calling a delegate function in another delegate function in a class in c#

Tags: c#, delegates

I write some delegate functions in a class one is as below

```
  public Func<string, DateTime> toGeorgianDate = persianDatestr =>
    {
        string[] persianDateParts = persianDatestr.Split(new char[] { '/', ':', ' ' });
        int persianYear = int.Parse(persianDateParts[0]);
        int persianMonth = int.Parse(persianDateParts[1]);
        int persianDay = int.Parse(persianDateParts[2]);
        int persianHour = int.Parse(persianDateParts[3]);
        int persianMinute = int.Parse(persianDateParts[4]);
        int persianSecond = int.Parse(persianDateParts[5]);
        PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();
        DateTime GeorgianDate = new DateTime(persianYear, persianMonth, persianDay,persianHour,persianMinute,persianSecond,pc);
        return GeorgianDate;
    };
```

I want to call toGeorgianDate in the below func, how can I call it?

```
    public Func<DateTime, int> PersianYear = GeorgianDateTime =>
       {

           return ;
       };
```

Comment: You can call/invoke a delegate like any other function. In your case: `toGeorgianDate(whateverString, whateverDateTime);`. It doesn't matter if the call is within another delegate function or not. Just make sure that the field toGeorgianDate is accessible from wherever you have declared the delegate PersianYear. (Otherwise the compiler will not be amused, obviously)

Comment: You need a string argument.

Comment: @elgonzo I write this    string pesrsianstr= toPersianDateTimeSTR(GeorgianDateTime); but it make an error that a field initializer can not reference the non-static field, method or peoperty

Comment: What do i know? How could i possibly know what `toPersianDateTimeSTR` is? ;-)